# clipboard.write throws error "Type application/json not supported on write" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard

```js
const json = JSON.stringify(item);
const data = [
  new ClipboardItem({'application/json': new Blob([json])})
];
await navigator.clipboard.write(data);
```

The error is "DOMException: Type application/json not supported on write."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `application/json` is just not supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem/types

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by Konrad, `application/json` is not supported. A solution would be to write it in a file and then use `application/json`:

```
const json = JSON.stringify(item);
const file = new File([json], 'item.json', { type: 'application/json' });
const data = [new ClipboardItem({'application/json': file})];
await navigator.clipboard.write(data);
```

The Blob could work with `text/plain`.

Comment: Unfortunately, using this approach gives the same error.

Comment: what about 
const json = JSON.stringify(item);
const data = [new ClipboardItem({'text/plain': new Blob([json], { type: 'text/plain' })})];
await navigator.clipboard.write(data);

Comment: Yes, text/plain does work. However, I'm intentionally trying to use application/json, so that is more of a workaround than a solution.

Comment: @fr0 How is normal text different from json?

Answer (score 0):

try this

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/web-custom-formats-for-the-async-clipboard-api

```
const json = JSON.stringify(item);
const data = [
  new ClipboardItem({'web application/json': new Blob([json])})
];
await navigator.clipboard.write(data);
```